# Controller Variables are nil in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am very new to ruby on rails, but simple operation is driving me crazy

I am passing variables from Controller to View

But it's nil in the view I read all the questions similar to mine but none of them was the solution

I have a method called `news_read`

```
def news_read
    @name = "Come On "
end
```

And in the **right**  associated view `(news_read.html.erb)` I try this

```
<%= @name.inspect %>
```

But the value on the browser is

```
nil
```

I am having trouble with 3 hours ago and it's not working at all

Any help will be appreciated

**Edit**

I tried to log something but it has not being invoked so my routes look something like this

```
get "main/news_read"
  get "main/index"
  root :to => 'main#index', :as => 'main'

  resources :categories
  resources :testimonials
  resources :news
  resources :products
  resources :teams
  resources :abouts
  resources :main
  resources :header_titles
```

Comment: Are you sure the controller method that you think is getting called is actually being invoked? If you put a debugger or logger call in the action, does it get printed?

Comment: get "main/news_read" the log didn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that I was trying to specify another layout according to action name and that method was private I don't know why it prevent it but removing it fixed the problem

**It was like this**

```
    layout :resolve_layout


  private 
  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "news_read"
      "news"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
```

**The solution is this**

```
    layout :resolve_layout

  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "news_read"
      "news"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
```

Comment: The "it was like this" and "The solution is this" look identical to me. What am I missing?

Comment: private in the 2nd line :)

Comment: @RyanBigg if you know why can you please tell me why ?

Comment: I have no idea how this even relates to OP. I don't think private is the cause of your problems.

Comment: well I know it's OP related problem, but removing it fixed the error do you think that I should ask it here on stackoverflow why this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on your answer (not enough SO points) so I'm adding this here.

It seems like you were overriding the internal `ActionView::TemplateRenderer#resolve_layout` ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/TemplateRenderer/resolve_layout)), which I think isn't what you were trying to achieve and may have been causing you problems.

I suggest you rename that method in your controller to something else, but keep it protected or private so it won't be treated as an action method if you have liberal routing.

Comment: thanks for the info but still same result it must be something with OOP in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<%= debug @name %>
```

As far as I know `.inspect` returns hash/array as string.

Also consider adding to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

Then run `bundle install`

EDIT

In your routes try this

```
match 'main/news' => 'main#news_read'
```

Then you API is **localhost/main/news**

Comment: If I set the layout to false I can't get the value else I get it

Comment: That's the default routing, e.g., `get "main/news"` is shorthand for `match 'main/news' => 'main#news', :via => :get`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out check my answer